# Makefile doesn't permit incremental build

Tags: c, makefile

I have a makefile from an example project, and it unfortunately forces a re-build when any single file in the project changes.  I do not have a lot of experience with makefiles, so I'm not sure how to solve this problem.

The makefile defines the files to compile as a single variable `SRCS` like shown below.  Of course, there are about 40 files in this list, in quite a few different directories.

```
SRCS = \
  ../../src/file1.c \
  ../../src/file2.c
```

Then later it defines the build rules for each `.o` file generated from each `.c` file.

```
$(OBJ_PATH)/%.o: $(SRCS)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(filter %/$(subst .o,.c,$(notdir $@)), $(SRCS)) -o $@
```

According to make running with the `-d` option, all of the object files must be compiled again  when a single `.c` file changes because `$(SRCS)` is defined as a dependency above.

How can I change this so if a single file changes only the 1 `.o` file must be compiled again?

Comment: So, the goal is to flatten a given source tree into a single output directory containing the object files (implying that file names must not be used repeatedly)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution would be using `vpath`. Example code:

```
OBJ_PATH := build

SRCS := \
    src/foodir/foo.c \
    src/bardir/bar.c

OBJS := $(addprefix $(OBJ_PATH)/,$(notdir $(SRCS:%.c=%.o)))

vpath %.c $(dir $(SRCS))

all: $(OBJS)

$(OBJ_PATH)/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Answer (score 2):

Your recipe was written by somebody knowledgeable about makefiles; it is almost correct.  The one correction is, to move the `$(filter)` statement to the prerequisite line.  In this case, that is where it needs to be.

Once it is there, you need to make a few additional adjustments, which you can read about in the manual.  So, like this:

```
PERCENT := %
.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(OBJ_PATH)/%.o: $$(filter $$(PERCENT)/$$(subst .o,.c,$$(notdir $$@)), $(SRCS))
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will also work.

```
SRCS = \
  ../../src/file1.c \
  ../../src/file2.c

# Set prerequisites for each output .o file from the matching .c file
$(foreach src,$(SRCS),$(eval $(OBJ_PATH)/$(notdir $(src:.c=.o)): $(src)))

# Create pattern rule with no additional prerequisites.
$(OBJ_PATH)/%.o:
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $< -o $@
```

So it occurred to me that an, in some senses, even more minimal change would be:

```
$(OBJ_PATH)/%.o: $(SRCS)
    file='$(filter %/$(subst .o,.c,$(notdir $@)), $?)'; [ "$$file" ] && \
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) "$$file" -o $@
```

Comment: if you want to make a big change, then yes I like your solution better than mine.  I attempted to make as little a change as possible, because I thought the intent was good, just the execution a little south.

Comment: @MarkGaleck Indeed, your solution is definitely a more minimal change than mine. I just have a somewhat irrational desire to avoid .SECONDEXPANSION at all costs. =)

Comment: well actually, what happens is, the kind of usage of `.SECONDEXPANSION` that I have there, is _undocumented_.  If you carefully read the documentation, it does not follow that you can do exactly what I am doing. But it _should_ be that way, and in fact MadScientist confirmed that it "works".  I agree that if it can be done without, it is better done without.

Comment: @MarkGaleck What about your usage is undocumented?

Comment: Well, so what the manual says, is that there is "reading" of the makefiles, and then, the dependency tree is constructed and then the recipes are executed.  The value of a variable such as $@, is setup during the construction of the dependency tree, for implicit rules this happens multiple times (once for each node in the tree).  Now there comes "secondary expansion".  The manual only says, it happens after the first one.  It is clear, that it will start with the values of the ordinary variables, as they are at the end of the first phase.  But what about $@?  Does second expansion happen...

Comment: after the tree construction or before?  Not clear from the manual exactly what the relationship is.  I pointed this out to God (MadScientist) and he did not say, here, it is written here, he said "it works".

Comment: Where does the manual say that `$@` is set at tree creation time? The manual for "Automatic Variables" says "These variables have values computed afresh for each rule that is executed, based on the target and prerequisites of the rule." which implies that they are set at target execution time though that is likely an implementation detail more than a functional detail (you could fill those in at tree time at a cost of storage/etc.). That being said the secondary expansion manual section explicitly says that `$@` works for explicit rules and that static/implicit rules function identically.

Comment: It also seems clear that it would happen after the tree construction as that is documented to be part of phase one, but that might be too finessed of a reading to be generally appropriate.

Comment: yes, I speculated on the time of creation of Automatic Variables, without having read the manual.  Thank you for pointing this out.  As for the secondary expansion saying explicitly what happens to $@, if my memory serves me, I remember when I looked at the manual, it was not there.  That's why I asked God, and that's what he had said at the time.  Maybe he updated the manual.  Or my memory is bad.  In any case, I am glad it is documented.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I learned a lot from your discussion and answers.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in a Makefile you do not put the specific .c files as dependencies.

Generally, you list the .o files as dependencies of the main executable.

Make has internal rules for figuring out how to build a .o file from a .c file,
you can override these with your own special rule, or often just changing a few
config variables is sufficient.

A complete tutorial on make is longer than I want to type in this box, but there are plenty of them available with a quick web search.

Comment: That is incorrect, in makefiles usually you do list "specific `.c` files" as prerequisites (that is the correct word).

Comment: make can (with some prodding on occasion) correctly build `.c` files into similarly named `.o` files. If that built-in works there is no reason to list those as prerequisites (but doing so does not hurt). You do need to list `.h` files/etc. though (or use automatic dependency generation to do that for you).